# Обработка изображения в ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phonegap, cordova, ionic

Есть мобильное приложение на `ionic`.
Я получаю от пользователя изображение(с камеры или галереи, не важно) мне необходимо добиться следующего эффекта: все фото затемняется, остается активным только небольшой кружок, круг движется за пальцем пользователя по фото. Когда пользователь нажмет на кнопку - все фото обрезается до активного круга. Как такое вообще реализовать? В какую сторону гуглить? Какие есть готовые решения?

Comment: http://www.jqueryrain.com/?VAAZCOTI можно попробовать адаптировать под тач

Answer (score 1):

Для ionic1 вам может помочь:
https://github.com/andyshora/angular-image-crop

Что-то вроде:

```
<image-crop          
 data-height="200"
 data-width="150"
 data-shape="circle"
 data-step="imageCropStep"
 src="imgSrc"
 data-result="result"
 data-result-blob="resultBlob"
 crop="initCrop"
 padding="250"
 max-size="1024"
></image-crop>
```

и далее используете с модификатором avatar при отображении